# Not able to download war file from artifactory by the link created in jenkins console output log

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I have added Artifactory plugin in Jenkins and was trying to move the build to Artifactory with the help of the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. I have created a sample Maven project.
The build creation is successful and I am getting a URL of Artifactory on console output of Jenkins which tells that my build has been sent to Artifactory. If I am clicking the URL it, I should get my war downloaded but this is not happening. I am getting 404.

I am using Jenkins 1.617 and JFrog Artifactory 3.8.0

If I am using jfrog artifactory 2.6.4 its working but with other release its not working.

below is the log

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/jobs/TestJob/workspace/pom.xml to org.ABC/testapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/jobs/TestJob/workspace/target/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to org.ABC/testapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

channel stopped

Deploying artifacts to http:192.168.X.X:8080

Deploying artifacts of module: org.ABC:testapp

Deploying artifact: http://192.168.X.X:8080/libs-snapshot-local/org/ABC/testapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Deploying artifact: http://192.168.X.X:8080/libs-snapshot-local/org/ABC/testapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

Deploying build info to: http192.168.X.X:8080/test/build
```

Comment: Is the actual [`href`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) of the link to the `war` identical to the displayed link text? Is it the same as the actual URL of the `war'  via Artifactory's web interface?

Comment: no the war url via Artifactory's web interface has time stamp with the war name.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the log output is buggy. The url `http192.168.X.X:8080/test/build` should, of course, be `http://192.168.X.X:8080/test/build`.
Please report it in [GitHub Jenkins plugin repo](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jenkins-artifactory-plugin).

Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the http192.168.X.X:8080/test/build url. I did not have the privilege to post more than 2 links. so I was forced to post this URL.